# copy contents of vector into file

Tags: c++, stl

i have following code for copying  content of vector into file

```
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void dump(vector<int>& v){
    ofstream out1("C\\Users\\datuashvili\\Desktop\\vector.txt");

    if(!out1){
        exit(1);
    }
    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(out1," "));
}
int main(){

    ofstream out1("C\\Users\\datuashvili\\Desktop\\vector.txt");
    vector<int>v;
    v.push_back(100);
    v.push_back(200);
    v.push_back(300);
    v.push_back(500);
    v.push_back(1000);
    dump(v);

    return 0;
}
```

but when i simple run this code,,there is not written into file which is created on desktop,why?could you tell me what is wrong with this code?
EDITED:
here is  edited code which also does not work doesn't open files and also does not write,two version
1.version

```
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<ostream>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
void dump( vector<int>& v){
    ofstream out1(("C:\\vector.txt"));

    if(!out1){
        exit(1);
    }

    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(out1," "));
    out1.close();
}
int main(){

    vector<int>v;
    v.push_back(100);
    v.push_back(200);
    v.push_back(300);
    v.push_back(500);
    v.push_back(1000);
    dump(v);

    return 0;
}
```

2.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<ostream>   
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
void writeTo(const std::string& filepath,const  vector<T>& data)
{

 ofstream filestream("C:\\vector.txt");
 std::copy(data.begin(),data.end(),std::ostream_iterator<T>( filestream," "));
 filestream.close();

}
int main(){

   vector<int>test;
   test.push_back(1);
   writeTo<int>("C:\\vector.txt", test);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you debug it?  It `exit` firing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is this:

```
ofstream out1("C\\Users\\datuashvili\\Desktop\\vector.txt");
```

should be;

```
ofstream out1("C:\\Users\\datuashvili\\Desktop\\vector.txt");
               ^^^^^
```

You could have found this out on your own by running under a debugger, observing the exit status of your program, or by adding print statements to your program.

In a debugger, you would have stepped through your code and discovered that you hit "exit(1)". Alternatively, you could have added something like `cout << "Can't open file!\n";` to your `if` statement.

Comment: i have changed it, but no success yet?i have add cout<<"can't open file" in if statement  in case of can't open file,just shows me error,but no error too,what is problem?vector.txt is created  on desktop,i have created it by hand

Comment: "just shows me error, but no error too". I don't understand what you are saying. When you run your program, does your program display the error message, or does it not display the error message?

Comment: Also, I notice that you open the output file twice -- once in main and once in dump. Try opening it exactly once and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try to start with a simpler, working version, then change things one by one: this example will just create the file in c:/

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void dump( const vector<int> & v)
{
    ofstream out1("C:\\vector.txt");

    if(!out1)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(out1," "));
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>v;
    v.push_back(100);
    v.push_back(200);
    v.push_back(300);
    v.push_back(500);
    v.push_back(1000);
    dump(v);
    return 0;
}
```

As other people mentioned, your path is wrong (at least, missing the ":" in "c:\..."), and you should open the file in only one place.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rob commented your path is still wrong. You missed the colon after the disk identifier. Your path needs to be something like this: "**c:\....**"

And you still open the stream twice which on the second try might fail since this resource is locked by the first call.

Try someting like this:

```
template< typename T >
void writeToFile( const std::string& filePath, const std::vector< T >& data )
{
  std::ofstream fileStream( filePath );
  std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator< T >(fileStream, " ") );

  fileStream.close();
}

int main()
{
  ...

  vector< int > test;
  test.push_back(1);

  writeToFile<int>( "c:\\test.txt", test );

  ...
}
```

Comment: ostream_iterator is unknown for program why?

Comment: if <iterator> is included it should be known, its missing in Jem's code sample, so if you only pasted his code you need to #include <iterator> to make it work

Comment: should i create  new question

Comment: no just edit your question so that is resambles the current version of your code. But as i already mentioned i think you only need to "#include <iterator>"